# How to make app check an entered number and tell you if it is wrong

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I'm making a basic suduku app and the places that you have to fill in with a number is a text field. So I was wondering how I can make the app check to see if the number is what the correct answer is right or wrong and alert you some how if it is wrong. (Each puzzle will be on its own xml file.)

Answer (score 1):

If your input widget is a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) (for example [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html))., you can create a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and register it with  [`addTextChangedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).

[Here](http://www.androidadb.com/class/te/TextWatcher.html) are some examples.

Comment: its EditText what would i use for that

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, you'll need to use an `EditText` to obtain the user's input. Then add a `textChangedListener` to it via:

```
int userChoice;

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             userChoice = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
             if(userChoice == wrong) 
               //do something
             else 
               //do something else

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sudoku I would consider to cycle through e.g. images (0-9) trough clicking rather than rely on EditText or something similar since its only ten characters.